# Dynamic colsapn HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Would it be possible to not define a colspan with a number (colspan=1) but instead with a variable, using only HTML and CSS?

Like this:
numberofcolumns=5
colspan="numberofcolumns"

I don't want to change the numbers of the all the colspan declarations every time I add another column but rather a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be possible to not define a colspan with a number (colspan=1) but instead with a variable, using only HTML and CSS?

No.

> I don't want to change the numbers of the all the colspan declarations every time I add another column but rather a variable.

Generate the HTML programmatically then.

Comment: Could you show me an example?
I'm looking for a table with a header row, say 5 columns. The following rows need to align with one or more of these columns. After some time I might add a 6th column but don't want to make changes to each colspan of all the rows.

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Comment: How would you solve this? I'm both familiar with C an python but I should be able to understand java. Just nog really aquanted with HTML. Want to wrikt on this for a project

Comment: I'd start by picking a programming language and then learning typical ways that language is used in web programming.